# SQL good practices: should I use associative tables in this example?

Tags: sql

I want to link two tables: a "company" table and a "branches" table. I find two ways to do it:

Method 1:

[image: Method 1]

Method 2:

[image: Method 2]

In practice, I think that both ways work the same, but professionally speaking, I think Method 2, using associative tables, would be the proper way to do it following SQL good practices.

I would like to know which is, professionally speaking, the proper way to do it and why it is the proper way to do it. Thank you

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  You should tag only with the database you are using (although in this case, the answer is more about data modeling than a particular database, so a database tag isn't really needed).

Comment: Depends on your use case. Are you building an OLAP or OLTP? If OLTP, then likely method 1. If OLAP, then you want wide. This means having everything into 1 table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A company can have many branches.

But a branch (presumably) belongs to only one company.

This is not an many-to-many relationship.  It is a one-to-many relationship.  Your second method, with two tables, should accurately model this data.